# Solving Ax + Bx = b (same matrix in two equations)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I have a differential equation:

$y''(x) + \frac{1}{2}y'(x) = cos(x)$

$y''(x) = \frac{1}{h^2}A$**y**

$y'(x) = \frac{1}{2h}B$**y**

How do you solve for **y** ? I've only seen equations of the form A**x**=b before, but this one seems like **y** is dependent in two equations.  I know A and B. I believe that b would be cos(x).

Note for transparency: This is a MatLab homework assignment, but I'm confused about the actual math involved, so I've changed the actual equation slightly and omitted anything that would be for marks - tried to make it as conceptual as possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$y''(x) = \frac{1}{h^2}Ay$$
We know from equation 1 that 
$$y''(x) + \frac{1}{2}y'(x) = cos(x) \implies y''(x) =- \frac{1}{2}y'(x) + cos(x)$$
$$ -\frac{1}{2}y'(x) + cos(x)= \frac{1}{h^2}Ay$$
From third equation we know that 
$$y'(x) = \frac{1}{2h}By$$
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2h}By + \cos(x)= \frac{1}{h^2}Ay$$
Rearrange terms
$$   \frac{1}{h^2}Ay +\frac{1}{4h}By=\cos(x)$$
$$   (\frac{1}{h^2}A +\frac{1}{4h}B)y=\cos(x)$$
Which is of the form $Ax=b$ you already know
$$Cy=\cos(x)$$

Of course you can solve the first differential equation directly too to get $y(x)$

Comment: Something is weird thoug you have a matrix on the left side but a function on the right side. Are you sure about these three equations ?